# Select date from rangepicker

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am trying to add two dates in a `rangepicker`.

This is the command to select the date:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setDatePickerDate', (selector, date) => {
  const monthsShort = [
    'janv.',
    'févr.',
    'mars',
    'avril',
    'mai',
    'juin',
    'juil.',
    'août',
    'sept.',
    'oct.',
    'nov.',
    'déc.',
  ];
  const month = monthsShort[date.getMonth()];
  const day = date.getDate();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  cy.getBySel(selector).should('not.be.disabled');
  cy.getBySel(selector).click();
  // select year
  cy.get('.mantine-CalendarHeader-calendarHeaderLevel').click();
  cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderLevel').click();
  recurse(
    () => cy.get('.mantine-YearsList-yearsListCell').invoke('text'),
    (n) => {
      if (!n.includes(year)) {
        cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-calendarHeaderControlIcon').first().click();
        return false;
      }
      cy.get('.mantine-YearsList-yearsListCell').contains(year).click();
      return true;
    },
    {
      limit: 12,
    }
  );
  // select month
  cy.get('.mantine-MonthsList-monthsListCell').contains(month).click();
  // select day
  cy.get('.mantine-DatePicker-day')
    .contains(new RegExp(`^(${day})`))
    .click();
});
```

This is the code in my test:

```
    cy.setDatePickerDate(
      'filter-date',
      new Date('2021-07-01'),
      new Date('2021-07-05')
    );
```

My issue is that in the date field only the date 2021-07-01 is being filled and not the other one.

Any advise on what I am doing wrong please?

//updated question as the cy.getBySel(selector).click(); is an optional part

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setDatePickerDate', (date, clickOnDatePicker) => {
    const monthsShort = [
      'janv.',
      'févr.',
      'mars',
      'avril',
      'mai',
      'juin',
      'juil.',
      'août',
      'sept.',
      'oct.',
      'nov.',
      'déc.',
    ];
  if(clickOnDatePicker) {
    cy.clickOnDatePicker(clickOnDatePicker);
  }
  cy.wrap(date).each((date) => {
  const month = monthsShort[date.getMonth()];

//the rest is same code
```

clickOnDatePicker command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('clickOnDatePicker', (clickOnDatePicker) => {
  cy.getBySel(clickOnDatePicker).click()
});
```

My d.ts:

```
setDatePickerDate(object: { clickOnDatePicker?: string }, date: Date): void;
```

My test code:

```
cy.setDatePickerDate({ clickOnDatePicker: 'filter-date' }, [
      new Date('2021-07-18'),
    ]);
```

My test is failing with error:
`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-testid=Sun Jul 18 2021 04:00:00 GMT+0400 ()]`

i want to do the below if there is selector to click

```
cy.setDatePickerDate({ clickOnDatePicker: 'filter-date' }, [
      new Date('2021-07-18')]);
```

else: if there is no selector to click

```
cy.setDatePicker({[
      new Date('2021-07-18')], new Date[('2021-07-18')]);
```

Comment: It looks like your parameters in `setDatePickerDate` are backwards - try swapping `date` and `clickOnDatePicker` and see if that affects the outcome.

Comment: Then i get ```Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-testid=[object Object]]```
Nomally need to click on the selector first then choose the date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can make an outer layer of custom command to handle the complexity of different parameters?

You don't need to pass the parameters with brackets `[]` or braces `{}` if you specify the args with a spread operator like this: `...args`. The spread operator converts the list of parameters into an array.

Below I added `cy.log()` to show the args are correctly parsed

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('pickDate', (date) => {
  // here is only logic for picking one date, you can test it independently
})

Cypress.Commands.add('setDatePicker', (...args) => {

  if (typeof args[0] === 'string') {
    const selector = args[0]
    cy.log('Selector', selector)
    cy.getBySel(selector).should('not.be.disabled');
    cy.getBySel(selector).click();
  }

  const dates = args.filter(arg => typeof arg !== 'string')
  dates.forEach(date => {
    cy.log(date.toUTCString())
    cy.pickDate(date)
  })
})

it('handles a selector and two dates', () => {
  cy.setDatePicker('filter-date', new Date('2021-07-01'), new Date('2021-07-05'))
})
it('handles two dates', () => {
  cy.setDatePicker(new Date('2021-07-01'), new Date('2021-07-05'))
})
it('handles a single date', () => {
  cy.setDatePicker(new Date('2021-07-05'))
})
it('handles three dates', () => {
  cy.setDatePicker(new Date('2021-07-01'), new Date('2021-07-05'), new Date('2021-07-07'))
})
```

This is the log showing each variation of parameter lists is handled correctly

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aladin..Can you please explain the setDatePicker command?
is it two commands in one command? cannot it be done with normal if else..if it is two commands can it be broken into two?

Comment: It's a command that calls other commands - the same as the example you have in the question. This is called ***composition***. A much easier way to code because you can separate the functionality, testing each independently.

Comment: You can't use `if else` in a test very easily because Cypress commands are asynchronous. It's better to put `if else` inside a custom command as shown in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom command does not support passing in multiple dates as you have. You could run the command twice:

```js
cy.setDatePickerDate('filter-date', new Date('2021-07-01');
cy.setDatePickerDate('filter-date', new Date('2021-07-05');
```

Or, you could alter your custom command to take in an array of dates.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setDatePickerDate', (selector, dates) => {
  cy.wrap(dates).each((date) => {
    // code to execute
  });
});

cy.setDatePickDate('filter-date', 
                   [new Date('2021-07-01'), new Date('2021-07-05')]
);
```

Edit: From the comment, essentially "how do I conditionally check if the selector is disabled and only click then?"

```js
...
cy.getBySel(selector).then(($el) => {
  if ($el.prop(':disabled')) { // We have to use JQuery so that the test does not fail if the element is not disabled.
    cy.wrap($el).click();
  }
});
...
```

Comment: Thank you..
i need another advise..The part "cy.getBySel(selector).should('not.be.disabled');
  cy.getBySel(selector).click();" is optional because i do not need to click on the datepicker on a second time as it stays opened to select the 2nd range..Do you know how i can achieve this part?
```cy.setDatePickDate(
                   [new Date('2021-07-01'), new Date('2021-07-05')]
);```

something like this but this does not make sense.

Comment: Updated answer to include information on this.

Comment: Can't i achieve something like?

    if(clickOnDatePicker) {
      cy.clickOnDatePicker(clickOnDatePicker);
    }

Then below i put this part: cy.wrap(dates).each((date) => {
//if i click on the datepicker
    cy.setDate({ clickOnDatePicker: filter-date',  new Date('2021-07-18')});

//if i do not click on datepicker
cy.setDate(new Date('2021-07-18'));

Cypress.Commands.add('clickOnDatePicker', (clickOnDatePicker) => {
  cy.getBySel(clickOnDatePicker).click()
});  - my datepicker cllick command
my TS:       setDate(object: { clickOnDatePicker?: string }, dates: Date): void;

Comment: my test is failing by:
TS2554: Expected 2-4 arguments, but got 1
: An argument for dates was not provided

Comment: the check for disabled part can be skipped

Comment: Without including the Cypress code for your custom commands, the corresponding HTML on the page, and more precise instructions for your issue, I don't think I can help you troubleshoot. Comments aren't the best place to try and ask for additional help.